# PDF signature added in Linux seen as invalid in Windows, yet certificate chain is all there

Tags: pdf, certificate, adobe-acrobat

I signed a PDF document in linux using JsignPDF and my Globalsign certificate; all looks to be in order, see:

```
# pdfsig test_signed.pdf
Digital Signature Info of: test_signed.pdf
Signature #1:
  - Signer Certificate Common Name: blah@example.com
  - Signer full Distinguished Name: E=blah@example.com,CN=blah@example.com
  - Signing Time: Oct 04 2023 19:10:32
  - Signing Hash Algorithm: SHA1
  - Signature Type: adbe.pkcs7.detached
  - Signed Ranges: [0 - 160], [30162 - 38375]
  - Total document signed
  - Signature Validation: Signature is Valid.
  - Certificate Validation: Certificate is Trusted.

("blah@example.com" is masking my real address)
```

I moved it over to my Windows 10 machine and opened it in Acrobat Reader, which told me "The validity of the document certification is UNKNOWN.  The author could not be verified".  Opening the signature panel in Reader told me "Signature validity is unknown".

I clicked on "Certificate details" within the signature panel, which brings up a certificate viewer.  There are three entries in the chain: my own signature at the bottom, which is shown issued by `GlobalSign GCC R3 PersonalSign 1 CA 2020`.  Next up is that PersonalSign certificate (of course), shown as issued by "GlobalSign Root CA - R3", and at the top of the tree is `GlobalSign Root CA - R3`.  In all cases "The selected certificate path is valid".   All this is as expected.

Looking in Windows certificate store I do see "GlobalSign Root CA - R3".

So AcrobatReader tells me that the signature, which is carried out using a certificate whose chain includes a valid certificate within the Windows store, isn't valid.  Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: **SHA1** was broken for collision in 2017 (6 years ago) -- in fact the public _demonstration_ of this attack (by CWU+Google) was on PDFs! -- and has been widely prohibited for signatures since very soon after that. (It was already considered _obsolete_ as below the 112-bit strength standard by NIST and CABforum, and some others, in 2013-14.)

Comment: Signing with SHA1 in 2023 what is this nonsense?

Comment: Quite so, Ian.  I found it was the default in "JsignPDF" which is what I use; but it's easily changed and I have done so.

Comment: @HenryLaw - Submit an answer instead of editing your question to include the answer. *Having to purchasing the correct certificate, if that is the answer, is an acceptable answer.*

Answer (score 19):

The exact message says that the validity is unknown, not that the signature is invalid. This is *technically* correct, given that the signature algorithm you used (SHA-1) is known broken, which means that any signature using that algorithm cannot be trusted irrespective of the apparent validity of the certificate chain.

The exact details of *how* SHA-1 is broken are a bit off topic here, but the short explanation is that it’s been demonstrated to be possible to synthetically produce hash collisions with it (and in fact, the original demonstration of this was done using PDF documents), which means that it’s not possible to be certain that the document is the same as when it was signed (which, in turn, means that signatures with it can’t be trusted).

Try signing the document with a newer algorithm that isn’t known broken, such as SHA-256, and you will likely see the signature correctly listed as being valid.

Answer (score 1):

To sign PDF documents Globalsign offer a separate "Document signing certificate", which comes on a hardware token. And, at UKP328 a year, it's considerably more expensive than the "PersonalSign" certificate I've got...

Comment: This seems to describe a facet related to the answer, but not the answer itself.

Answer (score -1):

Globalsign is not listed in
[Adobe Approved Trust List Members](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/approved-trust-list1.html),
which might be why Reader is not accepting its certificate chain.

To add a certificate to be trusted, the following procedure
might work for you:

- Open the document in Reader
- Right-click on the signature and select "Show Signature Properties..."
- Click on "Show Signer's Certificate"
  (you might need to click on "Validate Signature" if all other buttons
  are grayed out)
- In the Certificate Viewer window, go to the Trust tab
- Click "Add to Trusted Certificates"
- Click OK for the warning
- Select all the checkboxes in the "Import Contact Settings" window
  and click OK
- Back in the "Signature Properties" window, Click "Validate Signature"
- If the procedure has succeeded, the signature will now be validated.

You will find a detailed description of the process with screenshots
to help with this procedure (although some small differences with yours
may exist) in the article
[Validating Digital signature in acrobat Reader](https://goaonline.gov.in/Downloads/E-sign_manual.pdf).

Comment: Gosh; that's a stopper.  I'm simulating what someone else will find if they open my document, so adding certificates isn't going to happen.  How very annoying: it seems that I've bought a duff certificate.  Thank you for the reply, even if it's not what I wanted to hear!

Comment: **GlobalSign IS listed on that page** -- just look in the US section.

Comment: Then something is wrong with the certificate, or this kind of certificate is not on the Adobe Approved Trust List Members. The right address is Globalsign Support, to find out why it's not supported in the Adobe list. Adobe Reader is supposed to refresh its list from this site every 30 days.

Comment: I added the certificate at the top of the tree for my personal certificate and it all validates now (with SHA-256: good spot).  But that's no good because my recipients won't do that (and indeed their systems may be locked down by policy to stop them even if they tried).

Comment: Something is wrong either with the certificate or with Reader. You could reinstall Reader, and if that doesn't work then try to contact Adobe Support on the one side and Globalsign Support on the other, as one of them might come back with something useful. If something is wrong with your certificate, Globalsign will replace it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed out on the SHA1 point. I leave my answer in case the described procedure can help somebody in the future.